# Must one always have one's passport when using NEXUS?

Tags: passports, borders, canadian-citizens, nexus

As of now, can a Canadian cross into the US by land or otherwise with just a NEXUS card or does one always have to show one's passport also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A NEXUS membership card may be used as an alternative to a passport when entering the United States:
>
> by air when used at kiosks at designated airports; and
> at all land and marine ports of entry.

From: http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/about-sujet-eng.html

However it would seem advisable in some cases to carry your passport with your regardless, perhaps in case of a visit to another country before return to Canada.

Comment: I forgot the name...Global something...but now I got thinking is there an international entry card without a passport?  :-)

Comment: Oh my...I always to check mark!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can most definitely travel into the US with only your Nexus Card, I do it frequently.

Comment: So there is no way someone would refuse entrance because one's passport is not on them?